# enumerate custom label

Tags: lists, enumerate

I writting a project documentation with LaTeX. I am doing the user requeriments and the structure that I want to put in the documents is something like this:

```
UR-1: The client ...
UR-2: ...
UR-3: ...
```

I've create an `enumerate` list like this:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item The client
\end{enumerate}
```

but this only put the number and the text. How I can put the label "UR-" before the number in all the `enumerate`?

Comment: You can also use the optional parameter `\item [UR-1]`, etc..

Comment: Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With enumitem package you can create your own enumeration using \newlist, where you can define view of it and then use it instead of default enumeration:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{UR}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[UR]{label=UR-\arabic*:}

\begin{document}
    \begin{UR}
      \item First
      \item Second
    \end{UR}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello I think the solution is good, but this doesn't work to me. I use a preamble where I put \usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{UR}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[UR]{label=UR-\arabic*:} and then I use the other part, but this can't work. Thanks for the response but I think I don't have the package enumitem. I'm using Fedora

Comment: Are you using `\begin{UR}` instead of `\begin{enumerate}` after adding this preamble? Could you send fragment of code?

Comment: I think that the problem is that I can't use \userpackage{enumitem}. This give me an error. It's problem of my texlive package in Fedora. I'll search a solution.

Comment: How to force a newline after the UR-*?