# enumerated labels in description list

Tags: lists, enumerate, description

I need to achieve similar effect like in this question:
[enumerate custom label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80380/enumerate-custom-label)

However I would rather use `description` list with enumerated labels. Like I would write:

```
\begin{description}
  \item[UR-1] blah blah
  \item[UR-2] foo bar
\end{description}
```

but without manual labels counting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just define your own counter:

```
% arara: pdflatex    

\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\newcommand*{\mycount}{\stepcounter{mycounter}\themycounter}

\begin{document}
\begin{description} 
    \item[UR-\mycount] blah blah
    \item[UR-\mycount] foo bar
    \setcounter{mycounter}{0} % if you want to use it again.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course you may add the "UR-" or anything else to the command `\mycount`. And you may define automatic labelling with help of the package `enumitem`. Bit it is not clear from your question, what you are achieving to do and why you want to have it as a description.

Comment: Thanks for fast and correct answer. I need it to list a lot of UR-x items and define them.

Comment: What does `\themycounter` do?

Comment: @WojciechKo It prints out the current number of your counter `mycounter`

Comment: @LaRIFaRI : How do you set bold for UR-item fields?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that quite easily with the `enumitem` package and an `enumerate` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\begin{enumerate}[label=UR-\arabic*., font=\bfseries, wide= 0pt, leftmargin=2em]
\item Some text, some text, , some text, some text, , some text, some text, some text, some text, some text.
\item Some more text, some more text, some more text, some more text, some more text, some more text, some more text, some more text, some more text, some more text.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]