# Margin problem with enumitem

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I'm using `enumitem` to have a custom enumeration like this :

> Step 1 : first step
>
> Step 2 : second step

I looked up [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80381/28926), and adapted it :

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries Step \arabic*:]
    \item Elliptic Key Creation :
    \item Exchange of Public Elliptic keys
    \item MasterSecret Computation
\end{enumerate}
```

Up to now it's okay.

I now have a margin problem. The text after the `\item` doesn't shift to the right, and so, as the `Step X :` is longer than a simple `-`, the `Step X :` appears in the margin, like this :
[image: MWE result]

Is there a way to shift this of the length of the `\item` text ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `leftmargin=*`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries Step \arabic*:,leftmargin=*]
    \item Elliptic Key Creation :
    \item Exchange of Public Elliptic keys
    \item MasterSecret Computation
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or set a proper `itemindent` if you want to control the indent.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries Step~\arabic*:,itemindent=3em]
    \item Elliptic Key Creation : 
    \item Exchange of Public Elliptic keys
    \item MasterSecret Computation
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @EisenHeim: You are welcome. The manual can be accessed at `www.texdoc.net` or run `texdoc enumitem` from your terminal. No need of reading the entire manual but refer to it when needed. Anyway some times we won't know what key word to search for. So, it is OK to ask questions :)