# Indention error with custom label within enumeration

Tags: enumerate

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80380/enumerate-custom-label/80381#80381) is a way to create a custom enumeration.  I simply would like to do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}
      \item[Stage 1.] First
      \item[Stage 2.] Second
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

However, the "Stage" part does not indent properly!  Any idea how to make this indent properly?

Comment: Well, use the features of the package used in the answer you link to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one of these, based on the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}[label=Stage \arabic*:, align=left ]
      \item First. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah.
      \item Second Blih blih blih. Blih blih blih. Blih blih blih. Blih blih blih. Blih blih blih. Blih blih blih. Blih blih blih. Blih blih blih.
    \end{enumerate}
    \bigskip

    \begin{enumerate}[label=Stage \arabic*:, wide=0pt, leftmargin=*]
      \item First. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah.
      \item Second Blih blih blih. Blih blih blih. Blih blih blih. Blih blih blih. Blih blih blih. Blih blih blih. Blih blih blih. Blih blih blih.
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]